# How do I make a file object that operates on only part of the underlying file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary file consisting of an N-byte header, followed by a data block. I have input describing the locations of various bits of data, as offsets from the start of the data block; i.e. *not* the start of the file itself.

I want to open the file in such a way that `seek()` calls (and anything similar) seek within the data block, not the whole file.

Some options I've considered:

1. `mmap`. Close, but its offset argument is limited to multiples of pagesize.
2. Subclass file objects and override `seek()` to add the header length. Google suggests this may be annoying to do right.
3. Slurp the whole file minus the header, then make a bytesio. Problematic if the file is huge.
4. Patch `seek()` on the opened file object. I think this might work but monkeypatching makes me nervous.

I think what I really want is something that looks and acts like a file object but only "sees" a portion of the underlying file. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: #2 is probably correct; it would probably be worthwhile to add your attempt to override `seek` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inheritance and monkey-patching, you forgot a simpler option: implement a file-like class which seeks the way you want.  Then you'll have full control and non-leaky encapsulation.

Comment: Oops, yes. I considered that but forgot to list it. I might be missing something, but it seems like that would require implementing the whole file-object interface just to adjust one function. I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`mmap` the entire file, and then use a `memoryview` of the data block you are interested in. Then offsets into the memory view will be relative to the data block.

Comment: The `memoryview` object won't have a file-like interface, though.